# Reversing camera

Tags: ford, fiesta

My wife owns a Ford Fiesta 1.6 d it has factory fitted reversing camera with the monitor being interior mirror however the last 6 months we have been getting a blue screen when going into reverse.so I removed the camera  and cleaned connections but still show a blue screen. In the end I left the camera disconnected.but still shows blue screen in reverse

Answer (score 0):

Given that you get a blue screen both before and after disconnecting the camera, then I would suggest that you have either a broken or disconnected joint behind the screen or a broken cable between the screen and camera.

Comment: Thanks mike for your input .will check wires between monitor and camera will let you know if it works.thanks